# How to return a custom array of objects in a function in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I can't able to return a custom array of objects from a function in swift. I am always getting `[(custon object)] is not convertable to '()'` error message. I think i'm violating some swift protocol. Below is my code. Please let me know which i'm violating.

```
import Foundation

class DataSet {
    var settings:Settings!
    var service:PostService!
    var currentBrand:Brand!

    init(){
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.service = PostService()
    }

    func loadComments(id:Int) -> [CommentsList]{
        service.apiCallToGet(settings.getComments(id), {
            (response) in
            var commentsList = [CommentsList]()
            if let data = response["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let comments = data["comments"] as? NSArray{
                    for item in comments {
                        if let comment = item as? NSDictionary{
                            var rating = comment["rating"]! as Int
                            var name = comment["device"]!["username"]! as NSString
                            var text = comment["text"]! as NSString
                            var Obj_comment = CommentsList(rating: rating, name: name, text: text)
                            commentsList.append(Obj_comment)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return commentsList //This line shows error as :  "[(CommentsList)] is not convertable to '()'"
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your return statement is inside the completion block of your web service, which returns nothing `()` - that's what the error means.

Methods that are wrappers around asynchronous web calls can't return values, because you'd have to block until the web call had finished. Your `loadComments` method should take a completion block parameter, which takes `[CommentsList]` as an argument:

```
func loadComments(id: Int, completion:(comments:[CommentsList])->Void) {
    // existing code
```

Then, replace your return statement with

```
completion(comments:commentsList)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the type signature of this function:

```
func loadComments(id:Int) -> [CommentsList]
```

You don't return anything. You call this function:

```
service.apiCallToGet( ... )
```

But, Swift does not return anything implicitly hence the `()` (which means `void`) in your error. The line the error is given is slightly misleading...